# How to form an array on each row from multi table join effectively in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have six tables that I need to join and return a large chunk of data from using PostgreSQL and Knex.js, or a raw query if Knex doesn't support it.
Accounts, students, cohorts, cohort types, skills, student skills.

I can join those from accounts to cohort types with no issue to return each student with relevant information on the account, student profile, and cohort/cohort type.

The issue is trying to add in the skills/student skills because each row could have multiple skills. These skills are formed across three tables.

Skills: ID PK, skill

Skill_type: ID PK, skill_id FK, type

Student_Skills: ID PK, Student_ID FK, Skill_ID FK

For the purpose of this query, the skill type does not matter. I need to return the skill name for each student skill, rather than the skill id.

Each student returned can have multiple skills, which is where I run into my issue. I essentially need to form an array on every row of the return with a column called Skills that contains all of the skills for that student id.
Example:

```
    "id": 1,
    "profile_pic": null,
    "location": "somewhere",
    "relocatable": true,
    "website": "some-site",
    "github": null,
    "linkedin": "linkedin",
    "twitter": "twitter",
    "first_name": "name",
    "last_name": "last",
    "cohort_name": null,
    "track": null,
    "skills": [
      "HTML",
      "CSS",
      "SASS"
    ]
```

The way I have currently successfully done this is to retrieve all students without skills and then do an individual query for each student to retrieve and amend their skills.

I feel it is probably very inefficient and very expensive in large data sets.

Alternatively, I could fetch all of the student skills and loop through each of the arrays, mapping in skills where the student ID matches. I'm not sure that this is the correct way either.

My current working code:

```
cards = await db("students")
        .select(
          "students.id",
          "students.profile_pic",
          "students.location",
          "students.relocatable",
          "students.website",
          "students.github",
          "students.linkedin",
          "students.twitter",
          "students.careers_approved",
          "accounts.first_name",
          "accounts.last_name",
          "cohorts.cohort_name",
          "cohort_types.type as track"
        )
        .innerJoin("accounts", "accounts.id", "students.account_id")
        .leftOuterJoin("cohorts", "students.cohort_id", "cohorts.id")
        .leftOuterJoin(
          "cohort_types",
          "cohorts.cohort_type_id",
          "cohort_types.id"
        );

cards = bluebird.map(cards, async card => {
        skills = await db("student_skills")
          .select("skills.skill")
          .innerJoin("skills", "skills.id", "student_skills.skill_id")
          .where({ "student_skills.student_id": card.id });

        return {
          ...card,
          skills: skills.map(skill => skill.skill)
        };
     });
```

Are there any SQL experts that may be able to assist me in handling this correctly?